# How do I check if two input fields have values using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to execute a block of code if two input fields have values. Here's the code that I have so far but I believe I typed the syntax wrong.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

 $('button').click(function(){

  if ($('#signonname').length > 0) && ($('#signonpassword').length > 0) {

    // do something

    } else {

          alert('Fields are not filled out');

          }

    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you believe that the syntax is wrong? Have you checked your console to see if you are getting an error?

Comment: There's a typo, you have a `)` and a `(`  too many

Comment: @Scott Marcus For some reason it's not working for me

Comment: Right now your `&&` is not encapsulated in the conditional `(...)` - You cannot do `if (ConditionA) && (ConditionB)`. It has to be `if (ConditionA && ConditionB)` or `if ((conditionA) && (conditionB))`. In addition to this, you're checking the length of the selector - not the length of the values.

Comment: @Santi  Ahh I see

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is that when you tell us things like "I think I have a syntax error" and "it's not working", you aren't really being helpful to us to be able to help you. As I asked earlier, did you open your developer tools and look at the console? Are you getting an error message there? When you say it doesn't work, why are you saying that? What happens?  The more information you give us, the more we can help you.

Comment: @Scott Marcus  Every once in a while I'll get a response like this and it usually comes from someone who may have an understanding but is use to receiving the information a certain way. You say "us" but as you can see most people who are responding to my question have a clear understanding of the issue I am trying to resolve. I looked into the console and I did not see an error. Since then Ive corrected the issue. As most of the people have pointed out I needed to check the `val()` as well as length. Sorry that I wasn't clear

Comment: As you seem to be relatively new to Stack Overflow, rest assured that my comment was not representative of my personal feelings, it was representative of the way Stack Overflow works. Very often, the people who give their time and knowledge won't bother to even look into the details of a question if the question itself isn't formulated well. This is the reason that your question has been put on hold - - It's really not appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you have too many parentheses, secondly, a jQuery selector always has length as long the element exist, you want to check the value using `val()`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('button').click(function() {
        if ( $('#signonname').val().length > 0 &&
             $('#signonpassword').val().length > 0
           ) {
             alert('Fields are filled out')
        } else {
            alert('Fields are not filled out');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
name : <input id="signonname" />
<br /><br /> 
pass : <input id="signonpassword" />
<br /><br />
<button>Click</button>
```

What you have is equal to

```
var check1 = $('#signonname').length;     // returns length of selector
var check2 = $('#signonpassword').length; // returns length of selector

if ( check1 ) && ( check2 ) { ... // syntax error ...
```

Note how that's a mismatch in parentheses

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you made syntax typo: i.e., you need to have $('#signonname').val().length instead of $('#signonname').length

input fields value can be get/set using $('input selector').val()

Look below for the updated code

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

     $('button').click(function(){

      if ($('#signonname').val().length > 0) && ($('#signonpassword').val().length > 0) {

        // do something

        } else {

              alert('Fields are not filled out');

              }

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info